# How do I find last pipeline run timestamp and status and pass it as runtime argument in cloud data fusion pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, pipeline, google-cloud-data-fusion, data-ingestion

How do I find last pipeline run timestamp and status and pass it as runtime argument in cloud data fusion pipeline? I need to find this to do incremental records based on last_updated column in the table.

I cannot find any macro or runtime argument in cloud data fusion pipeline that tells the pipeline previous run details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a natively-supported feature. You might be able to use an action stage to make an API call to the Data Fusion instance for a pipeline to get the last run, write it to a file, then use the [Argument Setter](https://github.com/data-integrations/argument-setter) or [GCS Argument Setter](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1168343055/Creating+a+reusable+pipeline+with+the+GCS+Argument+Setter) plugins to set this as a runtime argument to the pipeline.